Does a korban need to be glatt kosher?
We know that a korban needs to be free of external blemishes. But an internal blemish would obviously not be discovered until after shechitah. If it is not being eaten - eg., an Olah - would it matter if it was discovered to be treif?

Keep in mind that the Rem"an and many other Rishonim do not require the carcass have glatt lungs to be kosher, so long as sirchot are removable without destroying the integrity of the lungs. FWIW, OU glatt is practically Rem"a non-glatt, with some extra chumrot

There could be chumros attached to the offering, just like we there are special requirements for wine to be used for the offerings

I think you're asking "must an all-burnt korban follow the same damaged/diseased-organ checks as meat we eat today"; the answer is yes. The matter of "Glatt kosher" (as used colloquially to mean "stricter than absolutely necessary by law") is a distraction here.

A lot of chumros we do is because we don't know exactly how to determine if it's treif. I read somewhere once that the תבואות שור wrote a separate sefar on the halochos of Traeifes in the bais hamikdosh but he had it buried with him.

It definitely needs to be kosher. Rambam, Hil. Issurei Mizbe'ach 2:10-11:

בְּהֵמָה שֶׁנּוֹלַד בָּהּ אַחַת מִן הַטְּרֵפִיּוֹת הָאוֹסְרוֹת אוֹתָהּ בַּאֲכִילָה אֲסוּרָה לְגַבֵּי הַמִּזְבֵּחַ הֲרֵי הוּא אוֹמֵר (מלאכי א-ח) "הַקְרִיבֵהוּ נָא לְפֶחָתֶךָ הֲיִרְצְךָ אוֹ הֲיִשָּׂא פָנֶיךָ"... נִשְׁחֲטָה וְנִמְצֵאת טְרֵפָה הֲרֵי זוֹ תֵּצֵא לְבֵית הַשְּׂרֵפָה
When an animal contracts one of the conditions that render it treifah and cause it to be forbidden to be eaten, it is forbidden [to be sacrificed on] the altar. For behold it is written [Malachi 1:8]: "Present it please to your governor. Would he be pleased with you or show you favor?"... If it was slaughtered and discovered to be tereifah, it should be taken out to the place of burning.

If the condition is such that there would be an argument among the poskim whether it's kosher (which is, to oversimplify, the difference between glatt and non-glatt), then presumably one or another of the batei din in the Beis Hamikdash complex would have to rule on it.

In fact, on a Shabbos, when the only slaughtering permissible is that for the daily sacrifices, it could happen that they slaughter one animal and then realize its organs look diseased. They go find another one and start over. (Nor are they in any trouble, as they had operated with the best information they had at the time.)

The question asked about Olah, so note Chullin 11a https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=11 We wouldn't actually check, say, the meninges of a korban olah to ensure they were intact

@DoubleAA Nor do we check the meninges of any shechted animal, unless there's a reiusa. But if we discovered that there was a problem with them, making the animal treif, then yes, the korban - olah or any other kind - would be pasul.
